# Ubuntu Host OS with VM - What size should my root partition be to accommodate VM?

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox

I was wondering if I need to make the root partition larger to accommodate running another main OS through a VM?

I plan on layering windows, and other OS (through VM) on top of a ubuntu host machine.

I don't know if I need to make the root partition larger, or if the size needed for these VMs can come from the home partition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create the VMs on any partition you want.

I do not recommend to use the root path.

Comment: Perfect, so I can have them on the user partition. That makes sense I just wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your VirtualBox is just another app running in Linux. The Virtual Machines you create are really just data files for the app to execute.

Virtual machines have a virtual drive, which is also a file, that have their own boot sectors, etc.  So, you are really using the boot sectors and partitions from the virtual drive rather than from your physical hard drive that you boot when you turn on your computer.